# How to make text in HTML page clickable to redirect to external page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a ticket system, where I want to make user email clickable. (It's just text atm.) HTML of the div looks like:

```
<a class="hover-contact-box lowercase">f11111@gmail.com</a>
```

I've installed the extension 'Custom JS' for Chrome. Is it possible to write JS code that will allow me to convert this text into a link, that will lead me to backoffice, and put this mail into search box? Thanks.

**EDIT:**  Editing the HTML is not an option. I was wondering if there's a possibility to make the email itself clickable.

**EDIT:** I do not need a *mailto:*, i need redirection to external source.

Comment: care to give more information, when you say the `HTML of the div looks like` what do you actually mean, also what do you mean by `this text`

Comment: though i can not edit the html, was wondering if there's a possibility to make email itself clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you can't use jquery:**
Considering you have only 1 element with given Classname:

```
document.getElementsByClassname("hover-contact-box lowercase")[0].setAttribute('href', 'mailto:yourmailid@gmail.com?subject=Hello Everyone&body=Just want to say hello to you all!!');
```

If there are multiple elements having same classnames:
You have to iterate in the list returned by `getElementsByClassname` and do `setAttribute('href', ....)`

**If you can use Jquery:**

```
var elem = $('a.hover-contact-box.lowercase');
elem.attr('href', 'mailto:yourmailid@gmail.com?subject=Hello Everyone&body=Just want to say hello to you all!!');
```

Both example will make it a link such that:

1. mail to: yourmailid@gmail.com
2. Subject: Hello Everyone
3. Content: Just want to say hello to you all!!

**If you have full control on html page for editing:**

```html
<a href='mailto:yourmailid@gmail.com?subject=Hello Everyone&body=Just want to say hello to you all!!' > yourmailid@gmail.com </a>
```

Comment: Kudos for including jQuery / non-jQuery options.

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getelementsbyclassname`. [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an element. The class list is space separated, not a selector. Thus, you need: `document.getElementsByClassName("hover-contact-box lowercase")[0].setAttribute(...` or to iterate over all of the elements returned: `[...document.getElementsByClassName("hover-contact-box.lowercase")].forEach(el=>el.setAttribute('href',newInfo));`

Comment: Thanks @Makyen for pointing out. I considered as per Question to have ONLY 1 classname in whole DOM.  I edited my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this email clickable use href Attribute

```
<a href="mailto:youremail">email text</a>
```

in javascript you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hover-contact-box lowercase")[0].setAttribute("href", "mailto:yourmail");
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you could do something like

```
var email = $('a.hover-contact-box.lowercase');
email.attr('href', 'mailto:' + email.text());
```